# Pegar apenas um commit de um projeto do github?

Tags: git, github

Estou acompanhando um projeto passo-a-passo de um curso, lá fazem uma vídeo aula e no final dela fazem um commit no github com o conteúdo feito daquele projeto naquela aula... Afim de fazer junto e não simplesmente clonar o repositório inteiro com o projeto pronto eu lanço juntamente meus commits no meu github de cada aula da mesma forma que eles.

Porém cheguei no final de uma certa aula em que não deu certo, meu código foi o mesmo do professor porém lançou uma exceção e estou a tempos tentando achar aonde fiz errado e não achei... Queria saber se tem como eu clonar apenas o commit daquela aula que o professor fez, de modo que eu consiga prosseguir daquele ponto em diante sem pegar o projeto inteiro pronto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou te dar uma dica sem usar linha de comando :)

Siga esses passos:

**Vai na raiz do repositório e clica na lista dos Commits**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Agora veja a data e o Commite de onde quer seguir e clique nesse botão**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Agora basta clicar no btn "Clone or Download" que vc vai fazer o Download daquela versão.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> **OBS:** Essa download vai baixar o projeto completo até esse Commit, nada que foi comitado depois dessa data será baixado. Assim vc pode começar a partir desse ponto.

Answer (score 1):

Faz um checkout apenas do `commit_sha`

Repositórios Git tem esse padrão `https://github.com/<repo_name>/tree/<commit_sha>`

Tenta usar esses comandos deve funcionar

`git clone -n <repo_name>`

`git checkout <commit_sha>`

Comment: se eu dou o git checkout + o id do commit aparece fatal: reference is not a tree

Comment: E o git clone clonaria o repositório inteiro, não ?

Comment: Sim  clona todo o repositório a partir desse commit