# Clonar commit de um projeto no GitHub

Tags: git, github, clone

Olá, pessoal.

Então, estou fazendo um curso de angular que possui um projeto hospedado no GitHub. Mas eu não quero clonar o projeto pronto. Eu gostaria de clonar/baixar o commit com a estrutura e estado iniciais do projeto. Nesse caso, é o primeiro ou segundo commit.

Tem como fazer isso??

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Pegar apenas um commit de um projeto do github?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356828/pegar-apenas-um-commit-de-um-projeto-do-github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode clonar esse repositório como está, e criar para você, uma branch a partir do commit desejado, ficaria assim:

```
git checkout -b minhabranch 6hjsb8da2f0e32ashi89998jnwbdeecb73fc892749ghbs7629
```

Com isso, você cria uma branch a partir do commit desejado